# Display float value in TextView using SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am using Custom `ListView` which contains `ProgressBar` and `TextView`. Now, Progress Data may contain `float` value so I want to display float value in TextView. But It is showing error : can not parse '43.20' to int. If I am passing int then It is working fine.

How to prevent this problem ?
**My Sample Code :**

```
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aaReportData, R.layout.report_card1, new String[] { "Topic", "Accuracy", "Accuracy" },
new int[] { R.id.tvTopic, R.id.pbTopicAccuracy, R.id.tvAccuracy });
```

`tvAccuracy` is the TextView about which I am talking.
**Log:**

```
03-11 12:32:38.913: E/AndroidRuntime(1187): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mytestbuddy.anatomy/com.mytestbuddy.anatomy.ReportCard}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '43.24' as integer
```

Comment: please show me error line.

Comment: First you need to conver Float progress data to String and after that pass that string to ur adapter.

Comment: did you tested my ans?

Comment: I am doing, give me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First u nee to convert floating values to string like this

```
String Str = String.valueOf("43.50");
```

Then assign str to textview.

```
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
txt.settext(Str);
```

like this,Try this one.

Comment: i know this way but how to pass in SimpleAdapter. If Accuracy is not an int then It is showing parsing error.

Comment: on SimpleAdapter which you can see in post.

Comment: String Str = String.valueOf("43.50");final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aaReportData, R.layout.report_card1, new String[] { Str, Str, Str },
new int[] { R.id.tvTopic, R.id.pbTopicAccuracy, R.id.tvAccuracy });

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the float value

```
textView.setText(""+floatValue);
```

Comment: i know this way but how to pass in SimpleAdapter. If Accuracy is not an int then It is showing parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round() before typecasting using (int) should round the float to the nearest whole number

Comment: i know this way but how to pass in SimpleAdapter. If Accuracy is not an int then It is showing parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try this one also:

Float value = 30.0F;
Integer intValue=Integer.valueOf(value.intValue());

and then you can convert inValue to String format and then set String on Textview as you need.

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: i know this way but how to pass in SimpleAdapter. If Accuracy is not an int then It is showing parsing error.

Comment: Hey Jeeten ,can you pls tell me are you using seekbar for updating scrolling progress on textview?

Comment: It is ProgressBar. And it does not contain any timer or anything. It will be updated only when that activity will be opened.